# Nonsensical reputation gain for individual answers in the reputation history UI

Tags: bug, status-review, reputation, reputation-history

For some answers, the displayed reputation gain in the UI is nonsensical and doesn't match what I see under `/reputation`:
[image: reputation history showing 70 reputation gained yesterday, but one answer contributing 120 reputation in total]

These numbers don't even add up, and are way off. The actual `/reputation` change is:

```
-- 2023-08-25 rep +174  = 15818
 2  76969564 (10)
 2  76969564 (10)
 2  76977471 (10)
 2  76969564 (10)
 2  76969564 (10)
 2  76847905 (10)
 2  76847906 (10)
-- 2023-08-26 rep +70   = 15888
```

After some time, I get the correct results. I've reopened the reputation tab and now see something else. I'm not sure how to reproduce the wrong numbers.
[image: reputation history showing 40 reputation gained for the same question, as it should be]

The day before, I've received 174 reputation, and this used to be listed, though when I reopen the tab, it also gives the correct numbers now.
[image: the same answer as in the previous figure is displayed with 690 reputation gained from upvotes in a single day]

It looks like the summary is correct for the overall reputation gained that day, but the reputation change for specific questions or answers is totally off.

Comment: Actually, why it highlighted yellow in one screenshot and blue in another? Is it yellow for new reputation changes that you haven't seen yet?

Comment: Long standing bug - it affects only new reputation. You would see it if you go check on your reputation after accruing some. However, a refresh would "fix" it because it's no longer counted as new reputation. You can force the bug to appear if you add a `StartDate` parameter to the URL.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been broken since the last redesign of the reputation pages in late 2021 (see "[New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/271271)"). On both MSO and MSE, there are multiple reports of various inconsistencies in the displayed data, particularly for the most recent couple of days.

Comment: FAQ on MSE about the `{site name}/reputation` page, for reference: [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/335251)